Enable updating with useSyncExternalStore in React after an error was thrown?
I have a hook that expects useSyncExternalStore to return a truthy value, e.g.:
function useFoo() {
  const val = useSyncExternalStore(...);
  if (!val) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  ...
}

I thought if useSyncExternalStore initially returned a falsey value, then updates to a truthy value, React would rerender. However, after an error was thrown, it never renders, even though the value returned by useSyncExternalStore should've changed to a truthy value.
My theory is that useSyncExternalStore internally uses useEffect to run the subscribe function. After an error was thrown, useEffect never runs, so it never creates subscriptions. Is there a way to make useSyncExternalStore compatible with throwing errors?
